# Default container options is missing

Tags: cloudkit

I am trying to enable cloud kit for my app using instructions here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH2

the default container option is missing for me. My app is in app store and builds fine.

[image]